# ESB to ESB communication

Tags: jboss-esb

I am trying to develop a system that has multiple services say ServiceA and ServiceB and they are both part of different esb packages say ESB1 and ESB2.

I have developed these two services and the esb wrapper around them and deployed them to jboss server.

What i would like to do is have service A in ESB1 invoke Service B in ESB2 and get the response back from serviceB.

I found that the general approach is to have both services published to a common registry and make the service calls. Can some one give me more information on how this can be done. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are on the right path, you already decided to use a registry service. The idea is -- as you are aware I guess - to provide a registry service that has an index of the currently available services. The different customers of these services will then look them up via registry instead of calling them directly.

You ask about how to set up such a registry - this is imho not a topic which can be handled in an answer on Stackoverflow.

I would suggest you get into it a bit more first. A very good starting point is the official registry service documentation provided by JBoss.

Find it here:
http://docs.jboss.org/jbossesb/docs/4.5.GA/manuals/pdf/ServicesGuide.pdf

Here is another documentation by RedHat about the Registry:
http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_SOA_Platform/5/html/ESB_Services_Guide/chap-the_registry.html

I hope these will point you into the right direction.